# Android action bar item custom background

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and I'm trying to set a custom background on the action bar items.

I've tried:

```
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/customActionButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/customActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="customActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_black_translucent</item>
</style>
```

and

```
<item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/background_black_translucent</item>
<item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/background_black_translucent</item>

<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/background_black_translucent</item>
<item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/background_black_translucent</item>
```

but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually got it to work by setting the selectable item background property:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/background_action_item</item>
    <item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/background_action_item</item>
</style>
```

Thanks

Comment: hello,I tried the solution given over here. I am having some doubt here. Actually It changes the background color of home and title in action bar. If I want to avoid it what should I do.